# How many devices can be used simultaneously if using ObjectBox Sync to make synchronization?

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

We might have tens of millions of users in the future since our app is an Internet one serving users around the world.

I'd like to know how many devices can be used concurrently to make synchronization using ObjectBox Sync?

Answer (score 1):

We have seen 100.000 **concurrent** clients connected to a single machine. Depending on the details of your application, a single machine might already be able to serve the need. But of course, you would want to have a cluster anyway for different reasons. Thus, the load can be shared among the cluster nodes for additional scaling.